# Overlapping java-like interfaces in C++

Tags: java, c++, inheritance, interface

I've read on many places that Java's interface can be 100% emulated using C++'s abstract class with all pure virtual methods.

I'm trying to convert this piece of java code:

```
interface A {
    void a();
}

interface B extends A {
    void b();
}

class C implements A {
    public void a() {
    }
}

class D extends C implements B {
    public void b() {
    }
}

D d = new D();
d.a();
d.b();
```

into something like this in C++:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void a() const = 0;
protected:
    virtual ~A() {
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void b() const = 0;
protected:
    virtual ~B() {
    }
};

class C : public /*implements*/ A {
public:
    virtual void a() const override {
    }
};

class D : public /*extends*/ C, public /*implements*/ B {
public:
    virtual void b() const override {
    }
};

D d;
d.a();
d.b();
```

but no matter how hard I try, I always end up with C++ complaining about ambiguity and/or missing body definitions.

The idea is that I want to derive from "C" which contains some shared code for all classes (here: "D" but there's more of them) and yet maintain the promise that "D" is 100% interchangeable with any class implementing "B" (incl. the parts from "A").

The errors I'm getting with C++ code above is:

```
../untitled1/main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
../untitled1/main.cpp:39:7: error: cannot declare variable ‘d’ to be of abstract type ‘D’
     D d;
       ^
../untitled1/main.cpp:28:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘D’:
 class D : public /*extends*/ C, public /*implements*/ B {
       ^
../untitled1/main.cpp:7:18: note:   virtual void A::a() const
     virtual void a() const = 0;
                  ^
../untitled1/main.cpp:40:7: error: request for member ‘a’ is ambiguous
     d.a();
       ^
../untitled1/main.cpp:7:18: note: candidates are: virtual void A::a() const
     virtual void a() const = 0;
                  ^
../untitled1/main.cpp:23:18: note:                 virtual void C::a() const
     virtual void a() const override {
                  ^
```

Comment: Can you please show us a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and include the *actual* errors you get (copy-pasted, complete, in full and unedited)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: the code snippets *are* complete, I guess I don't have to supply a main() function. I've added the compiler output.

Comment: You may have encountered the *diamond problem*.

Comment: It often is not a good idea to simply convert Java code to C++ syntax. So be careful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a problem that is solved by virtual inheritance from `A`.

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void a() const = 0;
protected:
    virtual ~A() {
    }
};

class B : public virtual A {
public:
    virtual void b() const = 0;
protected:
    virtual ~B() {
    }
};

class C : public virtual A {
public:
    virtual void a() const override {
    }
};

class D : public C, public  B {
public:
    virtual void b() const override {
    }
};
```

The problem is that unless you specify that both `C` and `B` need to share an `A` sub-object (all derived classes contain their bases as sub-objects), the two sub-objects you get from inheriting both `B` and `C` will be unrelated.

In your original scheme, the implementation provided by `C` to the pure virtual member in `A` wasn't considered as an implementation for the same function required by the `A` in `B`.

Since now there is only one `A` sub-object, this problem goes away. But note that virtual inheritance is not without a price. So think if you really want to go with such a design.

Comment: SO at its best. I tried at least two different virtual inheritance schemes but since I had only vague idea how it works I failed. Thank you for the code & explanation.

Comment: @Steephen - I daresay I do not deserve credit for solving it. It was the language design committee who came up with the mechanism:)

Answer (score 0):

All what you need is implementation of a() in D class:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void a() const = 0;
protected:
    virtual ~A() {
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void b() const = 0;
protected:
    virtual ~B() {
    }
};

class C : public /*implements*/ A {
public:
    virtual void a() const override {
    }
};

class D : public /*extends*/ C, public /*implements*/ B {
public:
    void b() const override {
    }
    void a() const {
        C::a();
    }
};




int main()
{
    D d;
    d.a();
    d.b();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't really help sharing the common code in one class (C), would it. Imagine you have 20 classes inheriting like D.

Comment: So try change D class to something like that: 
class D : public /*extends*/ C, public /*implements*/ B {
 public:
  void b() const override {
  }
  void a() const {
   C::a();
  }
 };